# Getting elements and values from inside parent div of button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm still new to JS and jQuery, but I'm trying to learn how to get all the elements and the values inside a div when I click a button inside it.

I was able to get it working for a form when I used FormData to do it. I can't figure out how to do it with a div instead of a form. (I would just use a form, but can't for this unfortunately.)

Here is what I got so far, but I know I'm doing something wrong.

```js
$('button.browsePageImages').on('click', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Attempting Image Browsing: ");
  var myArea = $(this).closest("div");
  console.log(myArea);
  var myAreaData = new FormData(myArea[0]);
  console.log(myAreaData);
  var myFormID = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
  console.log(myFormID);
  var dataHref = $(this).attr('data-href');
  console.log(dataHref);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="browseImagesDiv">
  <h4>Image (Optional) <span></h4>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="This is the image description." />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="areaSection-15" name="image_url" value="" placeholder="Image URL Here"/>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-xs browsePageImages" data-href="15">Save Image Info</button></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray` for each input.

```
var myArea = $(this).closest("div").find(':input');
var myAreaData = myArea.serializeArray();
```

```js
$('button.browsePageImages').on('click', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Attempting Image Browsing: ");
  var myArea = $(this).closest("div").find(':input');
  //console.log(myArea);
  var myAreaData = myArea.serializeArray();
  console.log(myAreaData);
  var myFormID = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
  console.log(myFormID);
  var dataHref = $(this).attr('data-href');
  console.log(dataHref);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12" id="browseImagesDiv">
  <h4>Image (Optional) <span></h4>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="This is the image description." />
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="areaSection-15" name="image_url" value="" placeholder="Image URL Here"/>
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-white btn-xs browsePageImages" data-href="15">Save Image Info</button></span>
</div>
```